# npm WARN tarball tarball data for eva-icons@1.1.3, @angular/compiler@8.2.14, @angular/core@8.2.14 seems to be corrupted

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, npm, gitlab-ci

Whenever I try to build my angular application with my gitlab ci I get the following errors:
[image: error]

I also tried with npm ci because thats a cleaner way but it gives the same errors but also for the typescript package.

I tried clearing the cache on gitlab and updating my npm packages. Also deleted the `package-lock.json` file but that didn't fix it.

Build can be found here: https://gitlab.com/suitless/suitless-web/-/jobs/458920725

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly Verdacio is the problem. Because we set the default registry to our private npm repository. It will throw theses errors because the server has some memory issues. Just only use your verdaccio server to install the packages that are actually stored on there.